# Setting Iconfiguration in .net 6 and .net 5

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

This code is working fine in .Net5, But when I try to update to .Net 6 there is no Startup.cs class. How should I implement this?

```
public class Startup
{
  private readonly IConfiguration _config;
  public Startup(IConfiguration config)
  {
    _config = config;
  }
}
```

**Complete Program.cs**

```
using API.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();   
ConfigurationManager config = builder.Configuration;
IConfiguration _config = app.Configuration;


builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{        options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Using Sql Server 2022, Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: Can you post the code of your Program.cs 's Main and related functions?

Comment: read the .net 6 migration guide. it tells you how to replace startup.cs

Comment: And you are free to bring the startup class back. You are not required to use the new minimal hosting model and can switch back to the generic hosting.

Comment: @JimdeVries Program.cs added

Comment: is the answer link (ASP.NET Core 6 how to access Configuration...) marked at the top solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the web app builder and then you can access the configuration.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// builder.Configuration...
```

For more info, please read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-startup-with-the-new-minimal-hosting-model).